# Redirecting to Specific Discord Channel upon Clicking Toast Notification

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, toast

I've been experimenting with a Discord bot using the discord.py library, and it also makes use of the [win10toast-click library](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast-click/) for sending me clickable toast notifications upon certain events.

My code for a toast (which upon clicking, opens/redirects me to my Discord app) looks like:

```
toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast(title="Some title",
                msg="Some message",
                threaded=True,
                callback_on_click=move_to_discord)
```

where:

```
def move_to_discord():
    os.startfile(r"C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Discord Inc\Discord")
```

Is there a way, using discord.py or other means, to make it so that my Discord focuses on a specific text channel after clicking the toast and being redirected to the app?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with the discord client, with the browser version it is as easy as passing the channel id to the link. The Discord API is definitely not used for this purpose

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Thanks for the reply!